# Comparing two lists and return an error if at least one entry is same

Tags: java, list

I have an object `SalesType` with fields `SalesTypeId` and `SalesTypeCode`.

I have two lists list1 and list2.

```
List1={(1,10),(2,20),(3,30)}
List2={(1,40),(2,50),(3,20)
```

I am trying to compare the `SalesTypeCode` code in the lists and if it is same then it has to exit the loop and return lists has same field.

Below is what I did but it is not returning what I am expecting.

What did I do wrong?

```
List<SalesType> list1 =service.getAllSalesTypeCodes(form.getReqSalesTypeGroup());
        List<SalesType> list2 = service.getAllSalesTypeCodes(form.getSorSalesTypeGroup());
        if (list1 != null || list2 != null) {
            mainLoop:
            for (int i = 0; i < list2.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println("list2 " + list2.get(i).getSalesTypeCode());
                for (int j = 0; j < list1.size(); j++) {
                    System.out.println("list1 " + list1.get(j).getSalesTypeCode());
                    if ((list2.get(i).getSalesTypeCode()).equals((list1.get(j).getSalesTypeCode()))) {
                        System.out.println("equals..:" + (list2.get(i).getSalesTypeCode()).equals((list1.get(j).getSalesTypeCode())));
                    errors.add(ActionMessages.GLOBAL_MESSAGE, new ActionMessage(ActionErrorConstants.MESSAGE_EXISTS_SALES_TYPE));
                        System.out.println("breaking the loop");
                        break mainLoop;
                }
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: What is it returning? What are you expecting>?

Comment: If the salesTypecode matches in the lists then loop has to terminate and return a message like lists are having one or more same saleTypeCode.

Answer (score 1):

Override properly equals in the **SalesType** class (including HashCode) and then use

- **List#retainAll(...)** method

  or
- **List#.removeAll(... )** method